# How to get connection string?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, connection-string, mongodb-compass

I am using a Compass to manipulate with MongoDB which is installed locally.

Here is the path to host which contains the databases:

[image]

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&directConnection=true&ssl=false
```

When I click on connect button which you can see in the picture above, I see 4 databases:

[image]

How can I configure what is the connection string to the specific database (for example development) so I can use it on YAML file for connection to the specific database?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following syntax:

```
mongodb://username:password@host:port/[database]
```

ie. in your case:

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/development?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&directConnection=true&ssl=false
```